# Invoking firefox through selenium module in python, just hangs

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to invoke firefox through python. Code is shown below.
python version: Python 2.7.6 32-bit ; OS: Windows 7; selenium module used: selenium-2.7.0

Can someone provide some insight on what might have caused this?

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com") # Load page
assert "Yahoo!" in browser.title
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("p") # Find the query box
elem.send_keys("seleniumhq" + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(0.2) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://seleniumhq.org')]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find seleniumhq"
browser.close()
```

Comment: To give some more info, the script proceeds only till "browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox" . After that it just hangs. Firefox version is : 47.0.1

Comment: Have you installed the Firefox driver, which is separate from Selenium itself?

Comment: @holdenweb, yes, I have downloaded geckodriver from firefox website and the path of that is added to env_variables